# How to configure docker's iptables rule DOCKER-USER to restrict output?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, iptables

I'm running a container, and I want to only allow it to access specific ips. In other words, I want to reject most of the destination ips.

I have tried the following:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -o custom-interface ! -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j REJECT
```

But it rejects all the connection, I can't `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

It's really strange, I think I just block the output packets through custom-interface which would not reach xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. So all the incoming packets and output packets which would reach xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx are accept.

But it seems I'm wrong. Why? Any help is appreciate.

## Edit

The accepted answer shows how to configure incoming restriction, and then I have learned how to configure outgoing restriction.

### Create a BEFORE_DOCKER table

```
iptables -N BEFORE_DOCKER
```

### Default

```
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -j DROP
```

### Docker Containers Public Admin access (insert all your allowed IPs here)

```
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -o eth0 -d 172.114.1.23 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -o eth0 -d 10.129.172.12 -j ACCEPT
```

### Docker Containers Restricted LAN Access (insert your LAN IP range or multiple IPs here)

```
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -o eth1 -d 192.168.10.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -o eth1 -d 192.168.10.2 -j ACCEPT
```

### Last step is to insert this as the first table on the FORWARD chain.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -j BEFORE_DOCKER
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a BEFORE_DOCKER table with a default rule of REJECT, next step is to insert this as the 1st table on the FORWARD chain.

## Create a BEFORE_DOCKER table

```
iptables -N BEFORE_DOCKER
```

## Default

```
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -j DROP
```

## Docker Containers Public Admin access (insert all your allowed IPs here)

```
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -i eth0 -s 172.114.1.23 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -i eth0 -s 10.129.172.12 -j ACCEPT
```

## Docker Containers Restricted LAN Access (insert your LAN IP range or multiple IPs here)

```
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -i eth1 -s 192.168.10.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I BEFORE_DOCKER -i eth1 -s 192.168.10.2 -j ACCEPT
```

## Last step is to insert this as the first table on the FORWARD chain.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o docker0 -j BEFORE_DOCKER
```

HOPE it will help !!

Comment: I just cannot understand your answer... It seems configure an iptable to control which external ips have access to container. But what I want to control is which external ips that the container have access to. It is just diametric.

Comment: OK, although you gave the answer about incoming restriction. I have also learned how to configure outgoing restriction, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [1], you should use the `DOCKER-USER` chain:

> All of Docker’s iptables rules are added to the `DOCKER` chain. Do not manipulate this chain manually. If you need to add rules which load before Docker’s rules, add them to the `DOCKER-USER` chain. These rules are applied before any rules Docker creates automatically.

for example, if you want to block all containers within the `docker0` interface from accessing `example.com` - you'd do something like:

```sh
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -d example.com -i docker0 -j REJECT
```

[1] https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#add-iptables-policies-before-dockers-rules